# Angular 6: Mat-card Make Page Content Scrollable w/o using fixed prop

Tags: html, css, angular6, angular-material-6

I have a top nav, side nav and the main content of the page. On click, the tabs on the side nav should bring the div associated with the tab to the top of the page (This is a different issue i am facing as scrollTop method from JS isn't working, but I am able to use scrollIntoView() for now to get something going)

template

```
<mat-card class="main-card">
  <mat-card-title>Some title</mat-card-title>
  <mat-card-content class="main-content">
    <div class="div1">Div1 content</div>
    <div class="div2">Div2 content</div>
    <div class="div3">Div2 content</div>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

CSS

```
.main-card {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 700px;
}

.main-content {
  height: 1000px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

sidenav items

```
<div class="side-nav">
  <div class="mat-list-item" (click)="handleElemScroll(div1)">
    <span>Div1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="mat-list-item" (click)="handleElemScroll(div2)">
    <span>Div2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="mat-list-item" (click)="handleElemScroll(div1)">
    <span>Div2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

on the main card, I am unable to add the height prop to, even if I use !important. I've run into this issue with a few other times using angular-material. I am forcing a scroll, but mid way through the scroll, the entire page begins to scroll. Even though the height of my mat-card-content is set to be larger than the mat-card itself.

A few questions if anyone can guide me
1. Why does my entire page begins to scroll mid way?
2. Without making my side and top nav stick, how can I implement a scroll? Is my idea of using overflow, and making the inner container height larger than its parent container the correct idea here?

Thanks for any help